# Creating Contact Form using Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.5

I am trying to create a form using Symfony 2.5 using [this](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/validators-and-forms.html) tutorial, but this tutorial is using old version of Symfony. I can get the form to display and created the entity as well however I am now working on submitting the form. Following is the code from tutorial and this code is inside default controller `contactAction`

```
public function contactAction()
{
    $enquiry = new Enquiry();
    $form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Perform some action, such as sending an email

            // Redirect - This is important to prevent users re-posting
            // the form if they refresh the page
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_contact'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:contact.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

My main concerns is in the following section of above code

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bindRequest($request);
```

As you will notice it is using `getRequest()` which has been depricated and then my IDE is telling me `buildRequest` method cannot be found.

I will really appreciate if someone call push me towards the right path of converting the `contactAction` for symfony verion 2.5, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: The [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) provides almost the same case.

Comment: The answers have the Request portion correct.  Only @MatthewThomas shows that you no longer need to check for POST.  However, his solution uses annotations which may be confusing to you.

Comment: thank you all for the feedback i am going through the answers and trying to understand them, Since I am creating the form and it does not do anything yet so i also wanted to know how can i check the form data that was submitted? while using plain php print_r($_POST); would show form data, how can i view that using symfony?

Comment: Yes by using the request object something like $request->get('name of form or field') or even better the form object $form->getData(); inside the form submission but you really don't need to do this with straight entities unless your say sending an email and want specific data from the request header

Comment: Thank you all :) StackOverFlow rocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there are a few deprecated calls also I would really recommend going to the cookbook in Symfony. But anyway this below will help.

```
namespace myproject/mybundle/controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

Class Act //that is me ;) {

    /**
     * @Route("/contact", name="_lalalalala")
     * @Template()
    */
    public function contactAction(Request $request){
    $enquiry = new Enquiry();
    $form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($enquiry);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_contact'));
    }

    return ['form' => $form->createView()];
  }
}
```

You can shorten this code even further by using symfony services container to inject your form. I would recommend reading this it is pretty awesome. As you can re use forms anywhere :)

Answer (score 2):

Declare the action like this:

```
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
...
}
```

And import:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

And you will have the request inside your action, so you can remove this line:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
```

Comment: how can i check the variables that were submitted? while using plain php `print_r($_POST);` would show form data, how can i view that using symfony as the form currently does not do anything and i want to check if it is submitting the data or not

Comment: If you want to print the POST variables, do this: var_dump($request->request->all());

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `getMethod` to `isMethod` like

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
```

And then your can submit the request data to the form using `submit` like

```
$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
```

Alternatively you can use the [`handleRequest`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html) method that will handle the above 2 method in one go and then you can move on with the rest of your action like

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid())
    .. etc
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the request object, you have two possibilities. Either let [Symfony pass the request as an argument to your controller action](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-request-as-a-controller-argument) ...

```
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...
}
```

... or get the request object from the container.

```
$request = $this->get('request');
```

For the binding of the request to the form, [the manual states](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html#passing-a-request-to-form-submit-deprecated) the following:

> Passing the Request directly to submit() still works, but is deprecated and will be removed in Symfony 3.0. You should use the method [handleRequest()](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.html#handleRequest()) instead.

This way, the request binding part would look similar to this:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```